# What is the best technique to make amazing black and white photos?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, black-and-white

I use Photoshop and Nikon Color EX. Both are good at making black & white photos.

What techniques are good to keep the photos detailed and give them a lively look?

Photos have been shot during the day.

Comment: Are you specifically after post-processing help or how to take good B&W images from the start?  This is a very broad topic - you need to narrow it down. What have you tried, and is there something you are disappointed in and need specific help with?

Comment: @MikeW the photos need to have the high key look and it should maintain its detail.I am using Photoshop and Nikon Color ex.

Comment: I don't think there will really be one "best technique". What will be the best for one image may not necessarily be the best for another.

Comment: @sohaibshaikh Do you have an example photo?  Are you having a specific problem you want help with?

Comment: You should also add what kind of output media you are targeting. Display? Print?

Comment: What is the definition of a "great photo" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you reveal you're looking for a high key look.

No image processor will do that for you. To get a great high (or low) key image you need a great high(/low) key subject, color and light wise. Besides that you're exposure also needs to be spot on. Not to loose those details.

If these requirements are met you can even get great high key b&w shots with the in camera image processor straight on your flash storage in camera.

I have no idea what your experience is but it might be a good idea to set your Nikon to raw mode (so that you have maximum information) combined with a JPEG file and then select the b&w image preset (from neutral, vivid, default, ...). This way you keep the original raw image to process on a computer. Even in color if you want. While every shot is displayed in camera as a b&w image so you learn to see the light and focus on that only while shooting.